# Python scrapy: how to retrive content that javascript dynamically fill into HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, scrapy

In the following web page: https://englishteststore.net/test/listening/conversation/hard/test60/index.html, there are ten quizzes, only when you submit your choice by pressing the button 'SUBMIT', you can see the next quiz by pressing the button 'CONTINUE'(After pressing 'SUBMIT' button, the text content on this button will update to 'CONTINUE').
What I want to do is to get all choices (as well as listening scripts) of those 10 quizzes at one time. I have checked with Chrome web develop tool and found that during 'SUBMIT' button pressing, there's no any other request for getting content of next quiz, so I guess all content of those 10 quizzes are retrieved when this page first loaded and stored in javascript.
As this page is also dynamically loaded, so I use selenium and scrapy for getting whole HTML content.
Is there anyone knows how to get content of all the 10 quizzes at one time?

Comment: your code trials?

Comment: you have to `submit` through code and `crawl` each time. `scapy` downloads whole page, and you parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

iSpring tools are not so easy to fool...answer and question are stored (encripted) here:

```
<script>
        var data = "eyJkIjp7IlQiOiJFbmdsaXNoI....
```